# Steam won't show any interface to me (except automatic updates)

Tags: applications, steam

except automatic updates I have no interface from Steam at all since I tried to install it.

Doesn't somebody have this problem?

Comment: Did you install steam from the Appcenter?

Comment: I tried several methods : from AppCenter, from apt-get custom repos.

Comment: https://imageshack.com/a/img923/4213/o6YLag.png

Comment: The problem is I installed a lot of stuff, it would make a lot of time too to reinstall everything. If you cannot thanks anyway. There are a few programs which doesn't launch, Steam for gaming, NiceHash for mining, and BattleNet...

Answer (score 0):

open steam from the terminal and tell us that it appears in the terminal.

Comment: Here's what it does : https://imageshack.com/a/img921/175/Q77f3l.png

Comment: try with sudo apt purge steam, them sudo apt install steam. run with LC_ALL=C steam. Do you have the graphics drivers installed? try apt install libatk-adaptor libgail-common

Comment: I tried as you told me, still nothing coming https://imageshack.com/a/img923/9010/b1020V.png and graphics drivers are installed.

Comment: @JavierA, your participation is much appreciated. Please use the comment field to ask information and use answer field for direct answer to asker's question. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Thank you :)